# Find element nearest to a point with approximate height and width in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, puppeteer

Is there any way to find the nearest element to a point (x,y) with approximate height and width?
Even if there will be multiple components of the same height and width it should take the nearest one.

I am trying to create an approach in Puppeteer to identify the nearest element to a coordinate (x,y) while testing or web-scraping.

Answer (score 0):

You need to better define *nearest element* but once you do, write a `distance(point, element)` function, iterate all elements and take the smallest of those.

Let's go with the easy one, a distance to an element center of gravity.

```js
var stats = document.querySelector(".stats");
var element = document.querySelector(".element");

window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(ev) {
  var mx = ev.pageX
  var my = ev.pageY
  var str = "distance(" + ev.pageX + ", " + ev.pageY + ", elem) = " + distance(mx, my, element);
  stats.innerText = str;
})

function distance(x, y, element) {
  var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect() // modern browsers
  var x1 = rect.x
  var y1 = rect.y
  var x2 = x1 + rect.width
  var y2 = y1 + rect.height
  return Math.sqrt(((x1 + x2) / 2 - x) ** 2 + ((y1 + y2) / 2 - y) ** 2).toFixed(2);
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 1200px;
}

.element {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 300px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="stats"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
</body>
```

Now having that we can have a few elements to evaluate distance and choose smallest.

```js
window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(ev) {

  var mx = ev.pageX
  var my = ev.pageY

  var min = Infinity
  var chosen = null;
  document.querySelectorAll("body *").forEach(function(element) {
    element.classList.remove("closest")
    var d = +distance(mx, my, element)
    if (d < min) {
      min = d
      chosen = element;
    }
  })
  chosen.classList.add("closest")

})

function distance(x, y, element) {
  var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect() // modern browsers
  var x1 = rect.x
  var y1 = rect.y
  var x2 = x1 + rect.width
  var y2 = y1 + rect.height
  return Math.sqrt(((x1 + x2) / 2 - x) ** 2 + ((y1 + y2) / 2 - y) ** 2).toFixed(2);
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 1200px;
}

.element {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 300px;
}

.elem1 {}

.elem2 {
  background: blue;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}

.elem3 {
  background: yellow;
  top: 70px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  
  
}

.closest {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="element elem1"></div>
  <div class="element elem2"></div>
  <div class="element elem3"></div>
</body>
```

An improvement would be distance to closest corner. But also need to consider being on top of element and z-index and maybe more stuff.